# How can I save data from a number of arrays into one array?

Tags: c#, arrays

I want save data from all of these loops, so I would like to know how I could do it:

```
    public Bitmap[] fill(Bitmap[] cr)
    {
        Card a = new Card();
        Card b = new Card(); 
        Card c= new Card();
        Card d = new Card();

        Bitmap n = new Bitmap(100, 142);          
        cr = new Bitmap[10];

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {

            d.Num++;
            d.Color1 = new SolidBrush(Color.Blue);
            d.Color2 = new SolidBrush(Color.White);
            d = new Card(d.Color1, d.Color2, d.Num);
            d.DrawCard();
            n = d.DrawCard();
            cr[i] = n;

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {

            a.Num++;
            d.Color1 = new SolidBrush(Color.Yellow);
            d.Color2 = new SolidBrush(Color.White);

          d = new Card(d.Color1, d.Color2, a.Num);
            d.DrawCard();
            n = d.DrawCard();
            cr[i] = n;

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {

            b.Num++;

            d.Color1 = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);
            d.Color2 = new SolidBrush(Color.White);
            d = new Card(d.Color1, d.Color2, b.Num);
            d.DrawCard();
            n = d.DrawCard();
            cr[i] = n;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {

            c.Num++;
            d.Color1 = new SolidBrush(Color.Green); 
            d.Color2 = new SolidBrush(Color.White);
            d = new Card(d.Color1, d.Color2, c.Num);
            d.DrawCard();
            n = d.DrawCard();
            cr[i] = n;

        }

        // _deck = new Card[n];
        test.Add(cr);
        return cr;
    }
```

I tried using an `ArrayList` but it only gives me data for the last loop only.

Comment: can you fix the formatting of your question also have you used the debugger to pinpoint exactly which line is failing and or where in your code you are seeing unexpected results..?

Comment: @MethodMan unless he adds some text an edit will be difficult -_- too much code, not enought explanations (editor error)

Comment: _[How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really clear what you are trying to do. However, if you mean to return from your method an array (`Bitmap[]`) that contains in it, each `Bitmap` instance that is assigned to the variable `n` in each loop, the general approach would be:

Create a `List<Bitmap>` to which the objects can be added:

```
List<Bitmap> cr = new List<Bitmap>();
```

Then at the end of each loop, instead of `cr[i] = n;`, add the `Bitmap` object to your list:

```
cr.Add(n);
```

Finally, at the end of the method copy the elements from the list to an array:

```
return cr.ToArray();
```

The whole thing winds up looking like this:

```
public Bitmap[] fill()
{
    List<Bitmap> cr = new List<Bitmap>();
    Card a = new Card();
    Card b = new Card(); 
    Card c= new Card();
    Card d = new Card();

    Bitmap n;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {

        d.Num++;
        d.Color1 = new SolidBrush(Color.Blue);
        d.Color2 = new SolidBrush(Color.White);
        d = new Card(d.Color1, d.Color2, d.Num);
        n = d.DrawCard();
        cr.Add(n);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        a.Num++;
        d.Color1 = new SolidBrush(Color.Yellow);
        d.Color2 = new SolidBrush(Color.White);

        d = new Card(d.Color1, d.Color2, a.Num);
        n = d.DrawCard();
        cr.Add(n);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        b.Num++;

        d.Color1 = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);
        d.Color2 = new SolidBrush(Color.White);
        d = new Card(d.Color1, d.Color2, b.Num);
        n = d.DrawCard();
        cr.Add(n);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        c.Num++;
        d.Color1 = new SolidBrush(Color.Green); 
        d.Color2 = new SolidBrush(Color.White);
        d = new Card(d.Color1, d.Color2, c.Num);
        n = d.DrawCard();
        cr.Add(n);
    }

    return cr.ToArray();
}
```

Note that your original code had a number of other extraneous bits, mostly to do with allocating new objects that were promptly discarded. So there are some changes above that reflect cleaning up those errors as well. There are probably even more logic errors in the above code as well as the program as a whole, but I am ignoring those possibilities here, addressing only those things that seem *clearly* to be mistakes.

Comment: Thank you very much it is working properly, what i was trying to do was to to fill my deck with cards that i have drawn using the c# graphics. i Will try and reduce the card objects i have made . Thanks again @PeterDuniho